# How to send values like form-data postman - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm using `fetch` to send value to my server. my server is php.
when I send my values with postman my server response as well.

but when I want to send my values with fetch I cannot get them from server side.

postman:
[image]

my requestOption:

```
  const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(parms)
        };
```

my values sent to server but I cannot get them like postman form-data.

`parms` is a object variable. like:

```
var parms = {};
parms['tok'] = '35345345';
```

Comment: you dont need to json stringify them i tihink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `formData` as `fetch` body:

```
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append("tok", '35345345')
const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },

        body: formData
    };
```